# Error occuring while connecting USB camera and two arduino with raspberry pi simultaneously

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I have the following code for connecting one usb camera and two arduino board with raspberry pi.

```
import cv2.cv as cv, time
import numpy as np
import serial,time
ser1 = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
ser2 = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1')

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)

while True:
    try:
        for i in range(10):
                x = ser1.readline()
                with open("test1.txt", "a") as myfile:
                    myfile.write(x)
                img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
                print("Taking image...")
                cv.SaveImage('pic{:>05}.jpg'.format(i), img)
                time.sleep(2)
                y = ser2.readline()
                with open("test2.txt", "a") as myfile:
                    myfile.write(y)
                cv.WaitKey(1)

    except:
        continue
```

The camera is for taking continuous image frame and storing the latest 10 images in the current folder in each 2sec(Overwriting previous data). The datas from the arduino also logging into two separate text file. While running the code i am getting error messages as shown below.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo python accident.py  
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy  
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl S_FMT  
libv4l2: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy    
libv4l1: error setting pixformat: Device or resource busy  
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable to ioctl VIDIOCSPICT  

Taking image...
Taking image...
Taking image...
^Z
[4]+  Stopped
```

While I searched for this problem , I found that, all the USB port of rasp-pi having the same serial port.

Can anybody help me to solve this issue...